# Component is not found even though package has been imported

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I've required the packages(react, and belle) but when assigning it, it throws a not found error.

belle.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/babel-core/browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react-root"></div>
  <!--
    You can use browserify, webpack or similar tools
    to compile & combine your JSX code
  -->
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

belle.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var belle = require('belle');
TextInput = belle.TextInput;

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    return <div>
      <TextInput defaultValue="Update here and see how the input grows …" />
    </div>;
  }
})

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

I have installed the dependencies and saved them but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TextInput is not defined1.belle @ bundle.js:6s @ bundle.js:1e @ bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing **var** when you import **TextInput**. Change

```
TextInput = belle.TextInput;
```

to

```
var TextInput = belle.TextInput;
```